# Aggregation taking too long using spark over hbase (using shc 1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hbase

I'm ingesting streaming data into hbase. I have pre-splitted the HBase table by Kafka partitions. Using composite rowkey with combination of Kafka partitions, timestamp followed by some other columns to make it unique. 
With this approach I'm having really good throughput while inserting the data but I also have to aggregate the data on daily basis, which is terribly slow.

We observed that the number of Spark tasks triggered for `groupBy` or `count` is equal to total number of regions in which my table is spread.

Am I doing something wrong here? How can I limit the number of regions for a table in HBase ?

HBase create statement

```
create 'default:test', {NAME => 'data', VERSIONS => 1, TTL => '3888000'},{SPLITS=> ['10000000000000000000000000000000','20000000000000000000000000000000','30000000000000000000000000000000','40000000000000000000000000000000','50000000000000000000000000000000','60000000000000000000000000000000','70000000000000000000000000000000','80000000000000000000000000000000','90000000000000000000000000000000']}
```

catalog while inserting

```scala
def catalog = s"""{
  |"table":{"namespace":"default", "name": "test", "tableCoder":"Phoenix"},
  |"rowkey":"key",
  |"columns":{
  |"rowkey":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
  |"resource_id":{"cf":"data", "col":"resource_id", "type":"string"},
  |"resource_name":{"cf":"data", "col":"resource_name", "type":"string"},
  |"parent_id":{"cf":"data", "col":"parent_id", "type":"string"},  
  |"parent_name":{"cf":"data", "col":"parent_name", "type":"string"},
  |"id":{"cf":"data", "col":"id", "type":"string"},
  |"name":{"cf":"data", "col":"name", "type":"string"},
  |"timestamp":{"cf":"data", "col":"timestamp", "type":"string"},
  |"readable_timestamp":{"cf":"data", "col":"readable_timestamp", 
    "type":"string"},
  |"value":{"cf":"data", "col":"value", "type":"string"},
  |"partition":{"cf":"data", "col":"partition", "type":"string"}
  |}
|}""".stripMargin
```

Catalog to read

```scala
def catalog = s"""{
    |"table":{"namespace":"default", "name": "test", "tableCoder":"Phoenix"},
    |"rowkey":"partition:timestamp:id:parent_id:resource_id",
    |"columns":{   
    |"partition":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"partition", "type":"string"},
    |"timestamp":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"timestamp", "type":"string"},
    |"id":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"id", "type":"string"},
    |"parent_id":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"parent_id", "type":"string"},
    |"resource_id":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"resource_id", "type":"string"},
    |"resource_name":{"cf":"data", "col":"resource_name", "type":"string"}, 
    |"parent_name":{"cf":"data", "col":"parent_name", "type":"string"},
    |"name":{"cf":"data", "col":"name", "type":"string"},
    |"value":{"cf":"data", "col":"value", "type":"string"},
    |"readable_timestamp":{"cf":"data", "col":"readable_timestamp", "type":"string"}
    |}
    |}""".stripMargin
```

To do range scan I'm using all the partitions and the time range:

```scala
val endrow = "1540080000000"
val startrow = "1539993600000"

df.filter(($"partition"==="0" && ($"timestamp" >= startrow && $"timestamp" <= endrow)) ||($"partition"==="1" && ($"timestamp" >= startrow && $"timestamp" <= endrow))||($"partition"==="2" && ($"timestamp" >= startrow && $"timestamp" <= endrow))||($"partition"==="3" && ($"timestamp" >= startrow && $"timestamp" <= endrow))||($"partition"==="4" && ($"timestamp" >= startrow && $"timestamp" <= endrow))||($"partition"==="5" && ($"timestamp" >= startrow && $"timestamp" <= endrow))||($"partition"==="6" && ($"timestamp" >= startrow && $"timestamp" <= endrow))||($"partition"==="7" && ($"timestamp" >= startrow && $"timestamp" <= endrow))||($"partition"==="8" && ($"timestamp" >= startrow && $"timestamp" <= endrow))||($"partition"==="9" && ($"timestamp" >= startrow && $"timestamp" <= endrow))).count
```

Above filter results in 830 tasks which is equal to number of regions. 
Which is taking way too much time. How can I improve it ?

Comment: You'll have to check the execution plan, but in general connections cannot optimize logical disjunctions (`OR`) so it might be just fetch-all-filter-later type of thing. See for example https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc#partition-pruning

Also the query seems unnecessarily complicated - if you distribute it should be just `$"partition".sin("1", "2", ...9) and ($"timestamp" >= startrow && $"timestamp" <= endrow)`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I realized that this rowkey design is not going to work for me so I'm using the similar rowkey design as mentioned in opentsdb i.e using metric_id as first part of the key. Also I changed the catalog while reading. Now I'm reading directly the rowkey instead of composite key and use filter as below : df.filter($"rowkey".startsWith("702200000\u0000"+currentDay)). Its much faster that earlier.

Comment: Please consider [answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) :)